# how to make data user specific in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancan

I have been working on learning ruby on rails and building web applications. Right now I am curious about how I can make data user specific in rails. I understand that I can use Devise for authentication. So that a user can sign in, sign out, sign up and so forth. Then for any type of authorization you can use something like CanCan. However I am interested in understanding how to separate data based off each user. For example if I have one user add a new task it is specific to their page. Another user will be able to sign in and see a different set of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

#### First you setup user has_many tasks relation

table User (id,username,...) and table task (user_id,task_name,task_note), the key for security is user_id inside task model, basically if user_id for the task created by specific user, can only be show/edit/destroy by that user only

#### inside task controller use [cancancan gem](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) to check the authority

after you checked the gem and know how to setup the ability class, the basic settings are as follows

```
can :update, Task, user_id: @user.id
can :read, Task,  user_id: @user.id
can :destroy, Task,  user_id: @user.id
```

these code above meaning Task can be edited/read/destroy **if the user_id of the task same with current_user.id** and [this link about defining ability in cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities%3A-Best-Practice)

Comment: Thanks this information is very helpful but I don't think it solves my problem. What I am trying to do is get each user to have a separate set of tasks. I don't want all users to be able to sign in and see the same tasks.

Comment: for your case then add additional column inside task model as task_group_id, if task_group_id = 1, then it for users with id=1, if task_group_id=2, then it for user with id=2, ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about [multi-tenancy](https://www.allerin.com/blog/multi-tenancy-in-rails) with Rails, give [apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) a look. This of course has to be done when you have a large set of resources(models) that have to be configured for various isolated tenants for your application. For eg. Various companies' admin login on a universal job portal. Otherwise it can be achieved without much hassle by using an extra check before all your multi-tenant resource queries. Again, all this is valid only if I understood your requirement correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Devise offers a variable `current_user`. Any relations related to the `User` model can be referenced. For instance, if a user `has_many :tasks`, you can reference each user's specific tasks by `current_user.tasks` within your controller and view.